# How to get the Type of the List item and add an object of that type?

Tags: c#, list, types

I have to fill a couple of lists. To void duplicate code I consider a generic method. How do I correctly get the Type of the list items and than create a new object of that Type?

Here is my rough idea how it should work:

```
public void fillLookups(List<object> myList)
{
    Type parameterType = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
    parameterType instance = (parameterType)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

    myList.Add(instance);
    ...

}
```

Comment: You have a list of `object` so you don't need to cast, and you can just check the type of `myList[0]`.. but what are you trying to achieve? There may be better ways available..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void AddSomeInstances<T>(List<T> list) where T : new()
{
    T newItem = new T();
    list.Add(newItem);
}

static void Main(String[] args)
{
    List<int> test = new List<int>();

    // 0
    Console.WriteLine(test.Count);

    AddSomeInstances(test);

    // 1
    Console.WriteLine(test.Count);
}
```